# How do I create a custom log file in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, logging, export-to-csv

I have this video playback project I built (many thanks to those who helped me solve some of the issues I had), and I was curious if it's possible to pass a string to a txt file? Heres an example of a CSV I would like to export to a text file.

Date, Time, No.VideoPlayed

`07/15/2015, 14:45:32, 340`

Is it also possible to do this without running a server? This is for local playback only.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the settings available in mm.cfg which generate a log file automatically for you if the SWF is running in a debug player. The ones you'll be most interested in are -

- ErrorReportingEnable
- TraceOutputFileEnable
- TraceOutputFileName
- MaxWarnings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to write to a file in your filesystem, then you should run your Flash movie as an AIR application. This way you'll have access to File class:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html